# Scroll window to the top of a div after sibling slideToggle

Tags: jquery, callback, slidetoggle

Hi there: I have a page of articles in divs that start off hidden behind clickable banners. Every time you click a banner, it extends the relevant article div with slideToggle and closes any other article div that is open with a slideUp. I've got the following code, which, if the view starts off above the final position of the clicked banner div, scrolls the window down to that div; however, if an article closes above that div, it will move up out of view, and then the window doesn't scroll up to it. How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".entry-title-thumbnail-active").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.site-content').find('.entry-content-thumbnail').not($(this).closest('article').find('.entry-content-thumbnail')).slideUp('slow');
        $(this).closest('article').find('.entry-content-thumbnail').slideToggle(
            'slow', 'swing', $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 'slow'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Basically, the logic moves up the DOM tree to the parent .site-content div, which contains all banners and article divs, then finds all child .entry-content-thumbnail divs and slides them up - excluding the sibling of the clicked .entry-title-thumbnail-active - to ensure no other articles are showing. Then it moves one level up the tree again to the article div containing all the sub-elements, and finds the .entry-content-thumbnail within that div and extends it.

The problem is, if a div does a slideUp above the div that is doing a slideToggle open, then the top of the article pulls up out of view, which makes for a not-great reading experience. I'm just trying to get the window to scroll back to the clicked .entry-title-thumbnail-active.

I put this in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JGuilford/VzVCD/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Some relevant html or a jsFiddle would be helpful for answering this.

Comment: You're right! http://jsfiddle.net/JGuilford/VzVCD/